# Raspberry Pi Not turning on

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, led

I just got a raspberry pi in the mail  from element 14. Its a model B. I also bought [this SD Card](http://www.newark.com/samsung/raspberry-pi-prog-4gb-sdcard/pre-programmed-sd-card-4gb-for/dp/96T7436) to boot from. When I first put in my SD Card and plugged in my power the PWR led turned bright red, then the green ACT light flickered. Then after a few seconds the PWR led would remain constantly red while all of the other leds would remain dark. After several attempts I believed that my SD Card was defective. So I [did this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MwdswCnv3rw). When that finished I put the SD card in the SD slot and then plugged in my power. Nothing changed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure that the write-protect switch on the card is fully in the read-write position (i.e. make sure it's fully unlocked)

Comment: @recantha is that when the switch is up (toward the connectors) or down (away from the connectors)?

Comment: On my card, the little switch gets pushed towards the connectors

Comment: Any display output?

Comment: *You have not actually described what's wrong*. My LEDs flicker for a bit when it boots too, then just the red PWR stays on after that, so I presume this is normal.

Comment: @ergosys nope. nothing.

Comment: I wouldn't rule out a display problem. But also see http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Power_.2F_Start-up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often times this sort of behaviour is a result of two common problems: an invalid SD card, or incapable power supply. What is the peak current rating on the power supply you're using with your Pi? The general rule of thumb is to use a power supply that can handle at least 1A of current.

Comment: my power source's output is 5.0V and 1000mA

Comment: hmmm bummer. Perhaps try performing a check sum on the SD card and compare it to the ones listed on the RPi foundation website.

Comment: How Could I do that on a mac?

Comment: My issue was an invalid SD Card. I had to reformat it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sorry I didn't reply to your earlier comment about instruction on doing a checksum, the notification must have been drowned out or something.